# Jquery Form validation plugin allows field that's required in rules: to be empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jquery validation plugin to validate a form submission. The validate is being triggered on submit and it runs but always returns the alert telling me 'valid form submitted', even though the fields are left blank in the form. It is like it is just completely bypassing the rules: section.

Here is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var form =  $("#task-form");
form.validate({ 

    rules: {
        assigned_to_user_id: {
            required: true
        },
        sourceable_id: {
            required: true
        },
        sourceable_type: {
            required: true
        },
        asset_list: {
            required: true
        },
        assignment_date: {
            required: true
        },
        expenditure_type_id: {
            required: true
        },
        inventory_stock_location_id: {
            required: true
        },
        inventory_quantity: {
            required: true
        }
    },
     submitHandler: function (form) { // for testing
        alert('valid form submitted'); // for testing
        return false; // for testing
    }
});
});
```

The html of just the form section of the page is 350 lines of code so I'm not sure if it is appropriate to post that much here. I'm hoping that my error is in the jquery code and someone can see it.

Comment: I just tested this exact code in another form (just changing the id of the form) and it works, so the problem must be in my html. Unfortunately, the page involved is very large and has multiple forms, this form alone is over 350 lines. Does anyone have a suggestion of what I should be looking for in the page? I have looked for duplicate ids but can't find any. Other forms have same form field names, but they are different forms so it shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: The burden is on you to construct a demo using least amount of code while still showing us the issue.  So if your HTML is 350 lines of code, what happens when you reduce your form down to one or two fields?  Same issue?  If it starts working, then you're on the way to solving this yourself... if not, then you'll have less code to post here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `"name"` attribute to your input fields on which you want validation to work and the `"name"` attribute should match the `rules`.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" name="inputUsername" placeholder="What you wanna know as?...."  >


rules: {
     inputUsername: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 4,
        maxlength: 10
},
```

Comment: Thank you koolhuman. Yes, I have names for all fields. Since there are some 20 forms in this page, the names are not unique but the IDs are. I ran the html through the W3 html validator and it found a problem with the open/close of the form that I am trying to evaluate here. There must be something broken because it says the < form> at line 537 has no close and the </form> at line 888 has no open. There are no nested forms in between. I keep searching for the issue - it appears it may be a stray <div> that isn't closed, but I can't find it.

Comment: Will you be able to post your html ? For validate plugin you should have unique name.

Comment: @circle1, if your markup is not validating as per the W3C HTML validator, then there's nothing we can do to help when we can't even see your HTML.

Comment: @circle1, methodically remove discrete sections of markup until it passes W3C validation... that's the only way to find where your error exists.